# Java object cache

Tags: java, caching, oracle-fusion-middleware

Is there a book or tutorials to know about Java Object Cache? I have a few questions here .

1. How do we setup in a distributed environment
2. Is there a maximum limit of objects which can be stored in Region / Sub Region.
3. Configuration to setup cache on Disk.

I have been going through this (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/core.1111/e10106/ha_cachewatch.htm) article but any other help would be great..

Comment: See: http://coherence.oracle.com/

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no general book on the topic Java Object Cache. Since we have a common standard now (JSR107), maybe it makes more sense to have something like that.

The approach you need to do, depends on what you need and how it works in the caching product you decided for. E.g. the "maximum limit of objects" is totally specific to a concrete product.

In the "distributed caching" area there are a number of products, that come with very useful documentation, tutorials and solution white papers. Examples:

- infinispan
- hazelcast
- gridgain
- oracle coherence
- IBM elastic caching (see also the RedBooks)
- teracotta

So there is a lot of information on the topic out there!